# How to copy a MySQL database to a machine which is not networked?

Tags: mysql

MySQL beginner here. I had thought that copying the directory `<mysql_path>/<data_base_name>` to USB stick & then copying it to the new PC would do it. It didn't.

Maybe I need to also copy schema or some such?

I can't say at the time of copying where it will be copied to & they might not be on the same LAN.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/copying-databases.html  seems useful, but too tricky for beginners. Similarly, using `mysqldump` and piping it on one line won't work as I don't know the destination.

What's the simplest no-brain way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
$ mysqldump -u user -p db_name > /machine1/your/portable/media/mysqldump.sql
```

and later, on the other machine:

```
$ mysql -u user -p db_name < /machine2/your/portable/media/mysqldump.sql
```

?

Here's a [simple guide](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/).

Comment: +1 and the answer. What's wrong with that? Why, nothing at all (nothing at all ... nothing at all ... Stupid, sexy Flanders!!)